# Functional Equation Different Substitution Different Result

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, functional-equations

Okay Consider this 
g(x).g(y)=1 for all x,y ∈ ℝ 
Substitute x=y we get g(x)= 1 or -1 
.Now Substitute y=1/x
 g(x).g(1/x)=1 we get g(x)=x^n 
where n∈N Different substitutions produced different solutions?

Comment: The second substitution does not give the solutions, only a superset of the solutions namely, all functions of the form $x\mapsto \alpha x^n$, $\alpha\in\{-1,1\}$. The only actual solution will be for $n=0$, since $\alpha x^n\alpha y ^n =\alpha^2 (xy)^n$ still must be equal to $1$ for all $x,y$. Put differently, both substitutions only give a necessary condition on the function; not sufficient.

Comment: Are we allowed to do any substitutions? When i substituted y=1/x, i implied that both x and y can't be zero but in the question given they can be any real number. Is the substitution incorrect?

Comment: Your substitution is OK -- but as said above and in the answer, this is not capturing the full condition. I.e., the original functional equation *implies* what you get after the substitution, but they are not equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that when you do a substitution, you *specialize*. Not any function, which is a solution of the substituted equation, is also a solution of the originial one, you have to check. In your cases:

(1) $g(x) = 1$ or $g(x) = -1$ for all $x \in \mathbf R$ is also a solution of $g(x)g(y) = 1$, but for example $g(x) = 1$ for $x > 0$ and $g(x) = -1$ for $x \le 0$, which is a solution of $g(x)^2 = 1$ for all $x \in \mathbf R$ does not solve $g(x)g(y) = 1$. Hence, the solutions of the originial equation are $g(x) = 1$ for all $x$ or $g(x) = -1$ for all $x$.

(2) If $g(x) = \pm x^n$, then the original equation reads $x^ny^n =1$ for all $x,y \in \mathbf R$. This is only true for $n = 0$. Hence, the solutions of the orignal equation are $g(x) = \pm x^0 = \pm 1$, the same as above.

Comment: Are we allowed to do any substitutions? 
When i substituted y=1/x, i implied that both x and y can't be zero but in the question given they can be any real number.
Is the substitution incorrect?